# Using Highcharts with minutes, seconds and milliseconds as Data not working

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, highcharts

I am trying to chart 1000 meters run, data is given via mySQL Database and brings MeterTime and urDate.  urDate is on the x-axis and y-axis should hold seconds.  But the chart either plots nothing at all, or everything on the zero line.

I understand I need to change how the charts interprets the time, but only the minutes, seconds and milliseconds are provided.  Not sure how I can convert it.

Any anyone see on the jsfiddle and check what i might be doing wrong please?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrAddy/wfvnLyzx/)

```
    var chart;

    var data = [{"urDate":"2015-03-04","urTime":"00:02:05","MeterTime":"00:15:534250"},{"urDate":"2015-03-06","urTime":"00:02:25","MeterTime":"00:18:019730"}];

    var options = {
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: '#34495e',
            plotBackgroundColor: '#2b3c50',
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: '',
            x: -20
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: []
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                name: 'Time'
            },
            type: 'datetime',

            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 1,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },


        series: []
    };

    var dataXAxis = [],
        dataSeries = [{
            data: []
        }];
    data.forEach(function (va) {
        dataXAxis.push(formatDate(va.urDate));
        dataSeries[0].data.push(formatDate(va.MeterTime));

    });
    // And assign the correct format to highcharts
    options.xAxis.categories = dataXAxis;
    options.series = dataSeries;

    // create the first chart
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    function formatDate(d) {
        d = new Date(d);

        var month = d.getMonth();
        var day = d.getDate();
        month = month + 1;

        month = month + "";

        if (month.length == 1)
        {
            month = "0" + month;
        }

        day = day + "";

        if (day.length == 1)
        {
            day = "0" + day;
        }

        return (day + '-' + month + '-' + d.getFullYear());
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I have changed the jsfiddle to include how the data is now loaded from the mySQL query.  Thanks to One, below, who gave me the idea to change how the data came in, rather than changing it once it arrived.

New Code looks like this:

```
        var options = {
            chart: {
                backgroundColor: '#34495e',
                plotBackgroundColor: '#2b3c50',
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: '',
                x: -20 //center
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: '',
                x: -20
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    name: 'Seconds'
                },
                //type: 'datatime', //y-axis will be in milliseconds

                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },


            series: []
        };

        var dataXAxis = [], dataSeries = [{data: []}];
        data.forEach(function (va) {
            dataXAxis.push(formatDate(va.urDate));
            console.log('t ' + va.MeterTime);
            dataSeries[0].data.push(parseInt(va.MeterTime));
        })
// And assign the correct format to highcharts
        options.xAxis.categories = dataXAxis;
        options.series = dataSeries;
        options.yAxis.title.text = 'Seconds';

// create the first chart
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    });
```

The main difference is how the data comes in:

```
[{"urDate":"2015-03-04","MeterTime":"15.5343"},{"urDate":"2015-03-06","MeterTime":"18.0197"}]
```

This comes from a mySQL Query that looks like this:

```
$isql = "SELECT urDate, time_to_sec(urTime) / (urMiles / 0.00062137) * 1000 AS MeterTime FROM results WHERE uid = " . $_POST['uid'] . " ORDER BY urDate ASC;";

        $ires = $mysqli->query($isql);

        while ($irow = $ires->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

           $data_result['userChart'][] = $irow;
        }

      echo json_encode($data_result);
```

And the end result, apart from some better styling, is this:

[image]

Hope this helps others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotted millisecond as Y axis.
http://jsfiddle.net/kjjn6tn3/3/

```
secondd = _.map(data , function (v) {return _.reduce(_.map(_.zip(_.map(v['urTime'].split(":"), function(v) {return parseInt(v);}), [60*60,60,1]), function (value , key) {return value[0]*value[1];}), function (x ,y ){ return x+y;})});
```

dataY = {
    name :"pump",
    data : secondd
}

same you can do with meter time and plot as Y axis.

Comment: I have marked it as correct, as it did work, but rather than the browser doing all the work, I changed the way the data came in.  Updated the code above for others to see.  Thank you One, you helped a lot in this :)